# WIX Desktop Shortcut - PathEdit Dialog Registry value

Tags: wix, shortcut

I'm creating an installer with WIX and want to get a desktop short cut. I have tried using the  method and get a desktop icon but it points to a folder and not the .cmd I want it to point to.

I have then tried using the  method show below. This then causes a problem on my pathedit dialog. My path edit defaults to c:\ but I want to install in program files (I want to this way round), but when using the registryvalue way to create a shortcut I get an error in the path edit window when selecting a folder within the C drive.

The error reads "The folder path '?' contains an invalid character". It will let me continue but I dont want the users to get this.

```
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
  <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="myapp">
    <!-- Folder Permissions -->
    <Component Id="SharedFolderComponent" Guid="*">
      <CreateFolder Directory="INSTALLDIR">
        <Permission User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes" />
      </CreateFolder>
    </Component>

    <!-- Desktop Icon -->
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
  </Directory>
</Directory>

<DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
    <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="*">
        <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartShortcut" Name="my POS" Description="Start my POS" Target="[#nodeployStartPOS.cmd]" WorkingDirectory="scripts" Icon="my.ico"/>
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Microsoft\myapp" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" />
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Regards

Chris